# Qt QWebEngineView in Windows: Can't show anything

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I really can't get QWebEngineView work on Windows 7. My code is like the following:

```
class Main:
     def __init__(self):
          self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)

     def getWindow(self):
          win = QMainWindow()
          win.setWindowTitle(self.winTitle)
          win.setCentralWidget(HTMLRenderer())
          return win

     def create(self):
         win = self.getWindow()
         win.show()
         sys.exit(self.app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
     theMain = Main()
     theMain.create()
```

And the HTMLRenderer:

```
class HTMLRenderer(QWebEngineView):
     def __init__(self):
         super(HTMLRenderer, self).__init__()
         self.setHtml('<div>Try HTML</div>')
         self.show()
```

But on Windows 7, I can see the main window but cannot see any HTML shown. But on Mac OS, everything works fine.

I understand that QtWebEngineView use Chromium as backend. Do I need to install Chromium separately on Windows? It seems that it is already included when you download Qt.

What seems to be the problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Chromium is packaged QtWebEngine, there's no need to install it separately. I do wonder if the problem is that you're calling `setHtml()` with invalid HTML -- there's no `<html>` tag, `<body>`, etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for response. But it works fine on Mac OS. So I doubt if it is not the problem of invalid html. In fact I have tried loading html from local file. but to no avail.